# Is this proper use of 敬語 in a business situation? ご所望の方の方がいらっしゃいましたら、日本語のメニューもご提供できます

Tags: politeness

For context, I am writing a menu for a made-up restaurant, and want to provide English and Japanese restaurants. This is an exercise I made up for myself. I want to include a phrase that is like, "A Japanese menu is available upon request." I have written this sentence, but I am not sure if the 敬語 is used correctly.

> ご[所望]{しょもう}の方がいらっしゃいましたら、日本語のメニューもご[提供]{ていきょう}できます。

I wanted to use the honorific form for 所望 (as it is describing the customer) and the humble form for 提供 (as it is the action of the business). I wasn't quite sure if 提供する should use ご～ or お～, but I think it is a Sino compound noun + する type verb I picked ご.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「ご​所望{しょもう}​の方がいらっしゃいましたら、日本語のメニューもご​提供{ていきょう}​できます。」

That reads quite well until the very end 「ご提供できます」.

Normally, you can only 提供する the items (dishes, drinks, etc.) on the menu, but not the menu itself.  Thus, unless you are actually selling the Japanese menu itself, it would be more natural and appropriate to say:

> 「日本語のメニューもご用意{ようい}しております」

Your choice of the honorific 「ご」 is correct for Sino-loanwords.